# create Crucible Review Precommit

Tags: pre-commit, atlassian-crucible

I want to create one Crucible Review ticket for Precommit review.

I am facing one issue like I am unable to find newly created Files in patch which is not yet commited on GIT.

Comment: Does the patch file you are uploading contain diffs for newly created files?

Comment: No. I am unable to get the newly created files in Patch file.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have added all the files to stage using `git add`, you can get the complete list of changes in a patch using `git diff --staged`.

Something like this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file1
#   new file:   file2
#
$ git diff --staged
diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index 5823f01..eb6be9e 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 sometthing
+line 2

diff --git a/file2 b/file2
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f138820
--- /dev/null
+++ b/file2
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+this is file2
```

So to create your Crucible pre-commit review, redirect the output to a file and then upload the patch file.

```
git diff --staged > patch.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this,

By attaching the Newly created files with "Attachment" Option.